# Flask handle POST as GET

Tags: python, flask, request

currently i have a Problem, where i send a POST Request but request.method returns 'GET'.
any idea?

my Code:

````
@app.route('/login1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login1():
    print(request.method)
    print(request.form)
    print(request.values)
    print(request.get_data())
    print(request.get_json())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST!!!")
    print(request)
    return str(request.is_json)```

JSON:
{
    "username": "aemail@mail.de",
    "password": "test"
}
````

Comment: please provide how you do a request to this endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you submit a form before you check if there was any request. If not try this:

**1. Create a form**

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <input type="submit value="Login">
</form>
```

**2. Check for any request**

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/login1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login1():
   if request.method == 'POST:
      # do something
```

You can also make a request via a button, a hyperlink and various other html objects. Sheers!

Comment: We have that problem, that we want to send JSON Data from the Client to our backend, but the backend only recognizes that as 'GET' method and no 'POST'. We tried to send JSON Data with the Postman Tool, but the Problem still stays on